# surface pro only displays on external screen

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, microsoft-surface-pro

I'm doing hardware support at a high school and I have a Surface Pro 7+ running Windows 10 and the screen is blank (black).

Weirdly the Windows logo flashes up on the screen for a second when booting before it all goes black. So the screen is capable of display, it just doesn't want to.

If I plug an external monitor in, the external screen displays correctly, but when I go into display settings, the laptop thinks it only has one screen and that's the external one.

I've run the latest driver pack, but it's not working either.

Signing in with a different account doesn't help so it doesn't look like a profile issue.

Has anyone else seen this? Any suggestions on how to resolve it?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRgzG8XIC0I / https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdPeAotRimY

Comment: FYI, I ended up taking the SSD out of the device and putting it another Surface Pro and it worked which made me think it was a hardware issue. Then I swapped the drives back again and suddenly the original device work! I don't understand, but it's working now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is solved.

Comment: The answer was given, meaning the question is completed, which does not mean it should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking the SSD out of the device and putting it another Surface Pro and it worked which made me think it was a hardware issue. Then I swapped the drives back again and suddenly the original device work! I don't understand, but it's working now.